# Flutter unable to swipe to go back iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

My Flutter app does not recognize the back gesture in iOS for back navigation. How can I make it work? Did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "*Did I do something wrong?*" -- How are we supposed to know *what* you did if you haven't posted any of your code?

Comment: Good point, I was hoping to come to this question as a blank slate, since I was under the impression this should come out of the box, but this happens also with just an out of the box app with material route to another page